# Read only file system while installing Flask on shared web server. Any workarounds?

Tags: python, linux, flask, server, cgi

I have bought a domain name and a shared server (linux) on bigrock. I have built a server on my local machine using Flask, and I wish to deploy it as CGI on the shared server. However, I am not able to install flask on the shared server.

On downloading Flask and running the following inside the flask directory:

```
python setup.py install
```

I get the following error:

```
running install

error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/test-easy-install-655838.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.
For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:
http://peak.telecommunity.com/EasyInstall.html
Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

Then I try,

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

and get the following output:

`-bash: sudo: command not found`

Then I try,

```
apt-get install sudo
```

and get the following output:

`-bash: apt-get: command not found`

So how do I install flask on this web server? Support for python is mentioned in the web server, and I have access using ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the system is basically telling you is that you have no permissions to install stuff in system wide directories (which is expected on a shared hosting).

You have 2 approaches possible:

- ask the sysadmin/support to install all your needed dependencies globally (which quite probably won't happen)
- ask the sysadmin of the box/support to install python-virtualenv so you have an isolated environment in which to install your copy of flask (if the host advertises support of python it is entirely possible you have virtualenv available.

Also check: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

Comment: Can I install Flask to a directory to which I have write access and then set this directory in the PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Comment: yes sure you can but still i'd go with the virtualenv solution. There is also the chance of needing other modules and it is better to have isolation.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This is not a new solution but an elaboration of a part of zeridon's answer, and is more relevant to BigRock Linux shared server.

**Opening of terminal and logging in:**

For windows users:
Install [PuTTY client](http://www.putty.org/). After installation, open the application and enter the Host Name (or IP address) as yourusername@yourdomain.com and open the connection. It will open a terminal and prompt for your password. Type your password and hit the 'Enter' button.

Mac and Linux users have terminal already installed, so just open it.

**Making of virtualenv:**

To make a virtuanenv with the name 'virenv', enter this command:

```
virtualenv virenv
```

This will make a directory with the name 'virenv' and will make a virtualenv along with pip installed.

**Activate virtualenv and install modules:**

To activate the virtualenv that was made, enter this command:

```
source virenv/bin/activate
```

After the virtuanenv is activated, enter this command to install a module.

```
pip install <module_name>
```

(For example, to install flask, enter `pip install flask`.)

**Usage in script:**

Get the path to virtualenv:
After activating the virtualenv, enter `which python` and it will give the path to the virtualenv. It would typically be something like '/home//virenv/bin/python'.

To use virtualenv in script, replace `!#/usr/bin/python` with `!#<path to virtualenv>`.

(For example, if the virtuanenv path is '/home/username/virenv/bin/python', use `#!/home/username/virenv/bin/python` at the top of your script.)